# What should be preferred, moving or forwarding arguments

Tags: c++, move, template-argument-deduction

Below is simplified example of the templated `List`, where are two `append_move()` and `append_forward()` functions that have the same goal, take the arguments and emplace them in to the container `List`. The first `append_move()` function takes `arg1` passed by value and then moves it to the `emplace_back()` function. The second `append_move()` function uses autodeduction of `arg1` and then forwards it to the `emplace_back()` function.

Does the `append_forward()` function have any advantages over the `append_move()` function and which function should be preferred?

```
#include <deque>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
class List
{
    public:
        void append_move(T arg1, std::string arg2)
        {
            list.emplace_back(std::move(arg1), std::move(arg2));
        }

        template<typename X>
        void append_forward(X&& arg1, std::string arg2)
        {
            list.emplace_back(std::forward<X>(arg1), std::move(arg2));
        }

    private:
        std::deque<std::pair<T, std::string>> list;
};
```

Comment: Consider what happens when you instantiate something like `List<int &>`.  Do you want to allow or forbid that?

Comment: append move will copy arg1 when called, append_forward wont

Comment: @ChrisDodd Will not work collections of references are not allowed either.  (unless you're willing to do some template specialization and start using std::reference_wrapper)

Comment: @PepijnKramer: it depends on the container -- they can be implemented to support references directly. That's why I asked whether you want to allow or forbid that.

Comment: @Kam If `T` happens to have any explicit single-parameter constructors, then the two would not even be equivalent from a semantic standpoint.

Comment: `append_forward` could potentially avoid one move, by taking an r-value by reference and forwarding it. I wouldn't count on that being the case after optimizations though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Forward or move

If `T`'s destructor can't be optimized out and produces visible side-effects, e.g.

```
struct Loud { ~Loud() { std::cout << "destructor\n"; } };
```

then

```
List<Loud> list;
Loud const loud;
list.append_forward(loud);
```

calls one less destructor than

```
list.append_move(loud);
```

because the latter constructs one more object => has to call one more destructor. So, forwarding is more preferable.

However, it makes the API less pretty:

```
another_list.append_move({"some", "arguments"}); // works and pretty
//another_list.append_forward({"some", "arguments"}); // doesn't compile
another_list.append_forward(Foo{"some", "arguments"}); // works
```

#### Overload by hand

So, unfortunately, providing hand-written overloads seems to be the best solution (for the user of your code) out of these three:

```
void append_overload(T&& t); // TODO actually implement
void append_overload(T const& t) { append_overload(T{t}); }
```

#### Emplace

However (once again), if you care about all of this, consider emplacing:

```
template<typename... As> void append_emplace(As&&... args) {
  list.emplace_back(std::forward<As>(args)...);
}
```

```
// works and pretty as long as you don't need to pass-construct two arguments
another_list.append_emplace("some", "arguments");
```

#### Other overloads

Besides, if you have more `append_*` overloads, note that forwarding/emplacing versions are less prioritized because of being templates. The choice is yours.

Comment: Thank you for exhausting answer. I have two questions. 1) When you spoke about _one less destructor_, do you mean the destructor of the copy of the passed object in the parameter `arg1` of `append_move()` function? 2) I'm little confused that you're using `another_list.append_move()` and `another_list.append_move()` functions with one argument, because in my example I'm using functions with two arguments. Is it just for easier explanation?

Comment: @Kam 1) Yes; BTW in that case `append_forward` gets a `const&` instead, avoiding the creation (=> destruction) of an unneeded object. 2) Yes; BTW implementing/using `append_emplace` can be unpleasant in your case (with two parameters).